# How can I open android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Im amateur for android developing. I dont know how to open any project on my computer.

http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/3156/35673611.png

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse, Use `File->Import->Existing Projects in Workspace`, then enter the path of the root folder of the project

Answer (score 0):

> File > new > project...
>
> In the wizard, choose android project
>
> Next button
>
> The new android project wizard will open. Change the radio button to
>   "create project from existing source "
>
> Use the browse button to find your project.
>
> Then select the finish button from the bottom of the wizard.

Source: [androidforums.com](http://androidforums.com/application-development/32654-how-open-project-eclipse.html#post229868)

Answer (score 0):

Open up Eclipse (or whatever IDE you use) and go to File>Open